# Centered layout with div borders on left and right (with bg images)

Tags: theming

I have begun a new theme on drupal using the Boilerplate theme.
I am trying to achieve a centered(responsive width) layout with borders on both left and right sides. I have attached a diagram. [DIAGRAM HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC9Ms.jpg)

I have the left side borders  working fine, they are within the #PAGE div which is the one and only WRAPPER of all content. (there is no other div above it)

As i have shown in the diagram, i am having trouble with the RIGHT side borders. With the same CSS syntax as the left borders, you can see they are positioned all the way to the right, even though they are inside the #PAGE div. Why is this? why is the #PAGE div not pulling it together?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT
`code`[jsFiddle demo/mockup](https://jsfiddle.net/rbptv8v1/)

PS- these 'borders' need to hold images as backgrounds so i can not simply use the 'border' property. And the 'border-image' is not well supported. DIV's is what i need.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not declaring the "borders" in CDs as border-left/right as declarations on the page div?

Comment: Like border-right:34 px solid your color

Comment: Yes, i will make it clear in the original post.
I need images inside the 'borders'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your example is that your "border" `<div>'s` have `position: fixed;` so they refer to the viewport rather than to the parent `<div id="page">`.

It's why you observe the right ones behaviour, which is pretty normal.
The left ones *seem* to refer to `#page`, only because they have not any `left` or `right` property set, so it defaults to `auto`.

Hence here is the first point: **you must set `position: absolute;` for these "borders".**

Additionaly you must remember that, for the `absolute` positioned element to refer to its nearest parent, this one must not have `position: static`, or another parent will be looked for as reference... till `<body>` if none is found, so it will be the same as for a `fixed` positioned element.

So here is the second point: **you must set `position: relative;` for the parent `#page`.**

From there you have to manage with `left`and `right` properties to get what you want.
You can look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbptv8v1/1/), where I added the needed properties to strictly conform to your [DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC9Ms.jpg) exposed wills.

Comment: This works very well, Big Thanks! the only thing is......when i begin to resize the browser window, #border1-l and #border1-r disappear. I cant manage to put a margin on, if i use margin-left/right then both borders are pushed Inwards rather than have an Outside margin. 

I cant use margin-left/right on #page because im using "margin:0 auto". Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand: I just controlled, not only with the fiddle but also creating an independant .html file, and borders never disappear. Only when the window becomes smaller than the whole picture, they're gracefully reduced till disappearing, yes, but seems totally normal in this extreme situation. So what?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean, the brown borders slowly dissapear. I can put a border around #page this works. I can also use margins on everything, but just a bit messy. I began reading about a spacer div, will try it later tonight -not at my computer.

Comment: Oh, if that's what you mean, I can't figure out what else you hoped? The only alternative I can think to is: when the window becomes too small, reduce the #page itself. You could get that simply replacing its width by max-width.

Comment: Oops... Don't pay attention to the previous comment: I'd thoughtlessly forgotten that #page already had a max-width, so this is not the solution. Fortunately, a few hours later, I was curious to examine it again and realized... But now I find a solution using jQuery, and it works: look at this [new fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/rbptv8v1/2/).

Comment: :D looks very promising! I have virtually no knowledge of jquery or any java stuff, i guess i need to look into it. Im having problems with Drupal running that script but im sure i will figure it out. Big thanks for all your help!

Comment: BTW note that jQuery is not required for that: I used it quite automatically but you can achieve [the same with pure JS](https://jsfiddle.net/rbptv8v1/3/). For how to include JS in Drupal, you may begin looking at [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722).